# In iOS 9, why is SFSafariViewController is being pushed instead of presented modally?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm presenting a `SFSafariViewController` by calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on a `UIViewController` instance.

The result is that it gets *pushed* on (slides in from the right), as if I called `pushViewController:animated:` on a `UINavigationController` instance. I've verified that this is all happening on the main queue. And the presenting view controller is not a modal itself (which shouldn't matter anyways, but just in case, we can rule that out).

If I substitute the `SFSafariViewController` with a `UIViewController`, it works as expected, it presents modally.

```
weakSelf.oAuthViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
[viewController presentViewController:weakSelf.oAuthViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any idea why or how to work around this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's a simple way to obtain a vertical modal presentation of a `SFSafariViewController`:

```
let safari = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
safari.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
presentViewController(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: While it works better when navigating back, this is not modal.

Comment: I found that `.overCurrentContext` works better since it also prevents a bug on iPhone X when status bar is hidden (transparent status bar area).

Answer (score 26):

I just had the same issue. Also, the done button work even if you don't set up the delegate. Not sure why it happens. However, I found a workaround: wrapping the safari controller in a navigation controller and hiding the navigation bar.

```
func openURL(url:NSURL) {

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        safariController.delegate = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: safariController)
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only method that works if you're using a custom transitioning delegate. If presenting the `SFSafariViewController` directly, then the transitionContext's from view will always be nil, even with other `modalPresentationStyle`s.

Answer (score 14):

To use the default modal transition style, you can simply set the transitioning delegate equal to self.

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
svc.transitioningDelegate = self //use default modal presentation instead of push
present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You'll need to adopt the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol in your view controller, but there are no required functions to implement.

This was mentioned in [Session 225 at WWDC, What's New in Safari View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/225/?time=1628).

Comment: iGerms solution is working, but this one is more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Objective-C version of iGerms answer:

```
-(void)openURL:(NSURL *)url {
   SFSafariViewController *safariController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:url];
   safariController.delegate = self;
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:safariController];
   [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```